# Which of these powers of $T-I$ are $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $V$ is a vector space over set of complex numbers with dimension $n$. $T$ is a linear operator on $V$ with only eigenvalue $1$. Then which are true and why?
>
> 1. $T-I=0$
> 2. $(T-I)^{(n-1)} =0$
> 3. $(T-I)^{n}=0$
> 4. $(T-I)^{2n}=0$

I do not understand how to approach

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The information about the eigenvalues is enough to determine the characteristic polynomial of $T$; use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

---

Because $1$ is the only eigenvalue, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ must be $(x-1)^n$.  By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $T$ satisfies $(T - I)^n = 0$.

Comment: Okk.. Thank you.. I will try

Comment: How to determine charateristic polynomial?

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Sorry for the delay. See my latest edit.

Comment: (T-I)^2n =0 this is also true

Comment: What is your name? What do you do?

Comment: Yes, $(T - I)^{2n}$ will necessarily be true, since $(T-I)^{2n} = (T-I)^n \cdot (T-I)^n = 0\cdot 0$. Conditions 1 and 2, however, will not necessarily hold. You can see some information about me on [my profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81360/omnomnomnom?tab=profile).

Comment: Where is your name.

Comment: Where is your name?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer